# Spectrum and Fourier transform of a sine wave

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, amplitude, rms

Take for example: $x(t)=A\sin(2\pi f_0t)$. The Fourier transform of this signal is $\hat{s(f)}=\frac{A}{2i}(\delta(f-f_0)-\delta(f+f_0))$. If we want to represent the spectrum of the signal we would compute the modulus of the Fourier transform, and it will look like the figure

[image]

So the amplitude at $f_0$ and $-f_0$ will be equal to $\frac{A}{2}$.

However, when I use an oscilloscope to compute the spectrum using FFT, the value of the amplitude is $\frac{A}{\sqrt{2}}$ which I believe should represent the RMS value of the signal. So my question is, how do we go from the first amplitude to the one we get on an oscilloscope, and does that have anything to do with power spectrum ?

I should also mention that the FFT computed on the oscilloscope contains positive frequencies only.

Comment: Because oscilloscopes don't usually show complex values, the FFT function has to take an absolute value. Because we're usually interested in power measurements, they generally scale to the RMS value. [See this post over on EE.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/150346/4338).